# How to connect Google Home to Harmony hub through SmartThings

Tags: google-home, samsung-smartthings, logitech-harmony

I've just got the Google Home, and SmartThings hub. My TV is already controlled with Logitech Harmony Hub (Smart Home Hub).

How do I set it up so that saying "Ok Google, Watch TV" would trigger the harmony activity to watch TV?

- [Harmony Smart Control](http://www.bestbuy.ca/en-CA/product/logitech-logitech-harmony-smart-control-915-000195/10242486.aspx)
- [SmartThings Hub](https://shop.smartthings.com/kits/samsung-smartthings-home-monitoring-kit) (I understand it's the V2)
- [Google Home](https://madeby.google.com/home/) (there is only one version)

Comment: Welcome, can you add a bit more information about the versions of the devices you are using?

Comment: @Helmar added links to devices. Is that what you needed? Thanks.

Comment: Can't you directly connect Harmony to Google home? I think Alexa talks to Harmony directly, not sure about Google home.

Comment: @edocetirwi not at the time of writing this question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Harmony Hub creates virtual switches in the SmartThings app. If you authorize these with Google home, you can issue commands like "Turn on Watch TV" or "Turn off Watch TV"

The Google home integration can be found under Things -> Voice Control in the SmartThing's Marketplace.

Comment: OK, so on the SmartThings app, under `Marketplace > Things > Voice Control > Google Home`, there are "Instructions", "Buy Now" and "Support Article". None of those let me "add" it. Same thing under `My Home > Add a Thing > Add Device Manually > Voice Control > Google Home`

Comment: Also, where do I add Harmony?

Comment: The support article has instructions. The Google Home has its own app and is added there.

https://support.smartthings.com/hc/en-us/articles/205653834-Logitech-Harmony-Home-Hub